# how to do sprinkle effect of water in opengl in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es2

I want to achieve sprinkling effect of water in android using opengl. 
so,
do i need to achieve it with graphics?
is there any other way to do it using opengl?

or how can i start working on this,any links?

Comment: you probably need a particle system for what you want to achieve and this means working on the CPU and with a physics library.

Answer (score 4):

As user827992 said you'll probably need to create a particle system. This does not mean you need a physics library in any way, however.

Spawn sparkles over the water of random size and placement between whatever specified thresholds you desire(just tinker with it till it looks purtty). Have them fade in and back out. You'll also need to control the rate at which the particle spawn.

There might be a library out there to handle particle systems for opengl-es, but I'm not sure.

Alternatively you can make an animation that plays over the water, or animate the water itself. However this is less dynamic and may look stale.